# How to ensure unique constraint is applied on multiple columns (mm_book_id and mm_author_id )?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I would like to know if anyone has ideas on how to ensure if in the join table `mm_author_books`, how to make sure the columns (`mm_book_id` and `mm_author_id`) are unique?
For instance, I don't want the table to contain duplicate records of `book_id` and `author_id` like 1,1 and 1,1. So how to do this...

```
class Book {
    String title 
    static belongsTo = Author 
    static hasMany = [authors:Author]
    static mapping = { 
        authors joinTable:[name:"mm_author_books", key:'mm_book_id' ] 
    }
}

class Author { 
    String name
    static hasMany = [books:Book]
    static mapping = { 
        books joinTable:[name:"mm_author_books", key:'mm_author_id'] 
    }
}
```

I have tried this in "mm_author_books" domain:

```
class mm_author_books {

 String book_agency_name    
 static constraints = {
    book_agency_name(unique:['mm_author_id','mm_book_id'])
    }
static belongsTo = [authors:Author, books:Book]

}
```

but getting the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.exceptions.ConstraintException:
>   Exception thrown applying constraint
>   [unique] to class [class
>   content_hub_admin.mm_author_books] for
>   value [[mm_author_id, mm_book_id]]:
>   Scope for constraint [unique] of
>   property [name] of class [class
>   content_hub_admin.mm_author_books]
>   must be a valid property name of same
>   class     at
>   content_hub_admin.mm_author_books$_*clinit*_closure1.doCall(mm_author_books.groovy:6)
>     at
>   content_hub_admin.mm_author_books$_*clinit*_closure1.doCall(mm_author_books.groovy)
>     ... 28 more

Thanks & Regards

rsheyeah

Answer (score 4):

the class mm_author_books (better name is AuthorBookRelationship) has no atributes mm_author_id and mm_book_id. Try this:

```
class AuthorBookRelationship {

    String bookAgencyName

    static constraints = {
        bookAgencyName(unique:['author','book'])
    }

    static belongsTo = [author:Author, book:Book] //only one author and one book

    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without create a many-to-many class?

Comment: @Luccas By default jointable du not support somthing like unique. But maybe you can declare the the many attribute as a Set.